# How to move String value to another column without replacing using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

Hi I'm trying to move the string values from one column and add it to another column.

For instance:

Initially I had a data as address in a single column like

```
5319 university dr, unit 143, irvine, CA92612
```

I split that column into multiple using the below code

```
new = Final["Address"].str.split(",", n = 3, expand = True) 
Final["Street"]= new[0] 
Final["City"]= new[1] 
Final["State"]= new[2] 
Final["Zip"]= new[3] 
Final.drop(columns =["Address"], inplace = True)
```

The output after splitting is below.

| Company | Street | City | State | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| company1 | 5319 university dr | unit 143 | irvine | CA92612 |
| company2 | 55 s Lake Havasu AVE | #F-109 | Lake Havasu | AZ-86403 |
| company3 | 31752 s.coast highway | suite 300 | Laguna BEACH | CA-92651 |
| company4 | 10115 e Bell Road | Ste. 107-232 | Scottsdale | AZ-85260 |
| company5 | 686 W SUNSET DR | BURBANK | WA | 99323 |
| company6 | 08 SE 124TH AVE | VANCOUVER | WA | 98684 |
| company7 | 23077 Boyd Rd | Mount Vernom | WA | 98274 |
| company8 | 456 Bellmore Ave | Manhattan | NY | 10025 |
| company9 | 81/8 lanscaster Sq | Austin | TX | 78753 |

I want the output as

| Company | Street | City | State | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| company1 | 5319 university dr unit 143 | irvine | CA | 92612 |
| company2 | 55 s Lake Havasu AVE #F-109 | Lake Havasu | AZ | 86403 |
| company3 | 31752 s.coast highway suite 300 | Laguna BEACH | CA | 92651 |
| company4 | 10115 e Bell Road Ste. 107-232 | Scottsdale | AZ | 85260 |
| company5 | 686 W SUNSET DR | BURBANK | WA | 99323 |
| company6 | 08 SE 124TH AVE | VANCOUVER | WA | 98684 |
| company7 | 23077 Boyd Rd | Mount Vernom | WA | 98274 |
| company8 | 456 Bellmore Ave | Manhattan | NY | 10025 |
| company9 | 81/8 lanscaster Sq | Austin | TX | 78753 |

Kindly help

Thank you

Comment: Hi sorry that i didnt include the full dataframe at firsthand. I thought i would be able to work from the first exmaple but its getting more complicated. kindly help

Comment: you have changed the question. what you had before had a different requirement. This makes this question a moving target, making it difficult for anyone to answer and resolve  it The question should focus on one aspect, to get a relevant answer

Comment: sorry for the trouble its my mistake

Comment: your data need more complex work because you want to move values only in some rows. I think you should start with column `ZIP` and extract `State` from `ZIP` to some temporary columns. And later use this temporary column to decide which rows need to move data from some columns to other columns.

Comment: did you create file with data? Maybe you should rather change code which generates original data.

Comment: Initially i had a data as address in a single column like 5319 university dr, unit 143, irvine, CA92612.

i split that column into multiple using the below code 
new = Final["Address"].str.split(",", n = 3, expand = True)
 
Final["Street"]= new[0]
Final["City"]= new[1]
Final["State"]= new[2]
Final["TBD"]= new[3]
Final.drop(columns =["Address"], inplace = True)

Comment: append it in question - it will be more readable. And more people will see it - so more people may help you.

Comment: you may need to use different indexes - and it may depends on `len(new)`

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# concatenate the street and city
df['Street'] = df['Street'] +' '+df['City']

# rename the columns
df.rename(columns={'State':'City', 'TBD':'State','City':'TBD'}, inplace=True)

# clear content of the column
df['TBD']=""

# re-sequence the columns
df=df[['Company', 'Street', 'City', 'State', 'TBD']]

df
```

```
    Company     Street                          City            State   TBD
0   company1    5319 university dr unit 143     irvine          CA  
1   company2    55 s Lake Havasu AVE #F-109     Lake Havasu     AZ  
2   company3    31752 s.coast highway suite 300 Laguna BEACH    CA  
3   company4    10115 e Bell Road Ste. 107-232  Scottsdale      AZ
```

Comment: Hi sorry that i didnt include the full dataframe at firsthand. I thought i would be able to work from the first exmaple but its getting more complicated. kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Let's do:

```
df = df.assign(
    Street=df["Street"].str.cat(df["City"], sep=" "),
    City=df["State"],
    State=df["TBD"],
    TBD="",
)
```

Comment: Hi sorry that i didnt include the full dataframe at firsthand. I thought i would be able to work from the first exmaple but its getting more complicated. kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Your new data (after updating question) needs more complex work because you want to move values only in some rows - in rows which have `State` in `Zip` (ie. `CA92612`, `AZ-86403`, etc.)

You should start with column `ZIP` and extract `State` from `ZIP` to some temporary columns.

```
df['temp'] = df['Zip'].str.extract('([A-Z]+)')
```

And later use this temporary column to decide which rows need to move data from some columns to other columns.

```
mask = df['temp'].notnull()

df['Street'][mask] = df['Street'][mask] + ' ' + df['City'][mask]
df['City'][mask] = df['State'][mask]
df['State'][mask] = df['temp'][mask]
df['Zip'][mask] = df['Zip'][mask].str[-5:]

del df['temp']
```

or

```
mask = df['temp'].notnull()

df.loc[mask, 'Street'] = df.loc[mask, 'Street'] + ' ' + df.loc[mask, 'City']
df.loc[mask, 'City']   = df.loc[mask, 'State']
df.loc[mask, 'State']  = df.loc[mask, 'temp']
df.loc[mask, 'Zip']    = df.loc[mask, 'Zip'].str[-5:]

del df['temp']
```

---

Full working example:

```
text = '''Company,Street,City,State,Zip
company1,5319 university dr,unit 143,irvine,CA92612
company2,55 s Lake Havasu AVE,#F-109,Lake Havasu,AZ-86403
company3,31752 s.coast highway,suite 300,Laguna BEACH,CA-92651
company4,10115 e Bell Road,Ste. 107-232,Scottsdale,AZ-85260
company5,686 W SUNSET DR,BURBANK,WA,99323
company6,08 SE 124TH AVE,VANCOUVER,WA,98684
company7,23077 Boyd Rd,Mount Vernom,WA,98274
company8,456 Bellmore Ave,Manhattan,NY,10025
company9,81/8 lanscaster Sq,Austin,TX,78753'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))
print('\n--- before ---\n')
print(df)

df['temp'] = df['Zip'].str.extract('([A-Z]+)')
print('\n--- temp ---\n')
print(df)

mask = df['temp'].notnull()
print('\n--- mask ---\n')
print(mask)

#df['Street'][mask] = df['Street'][mask] + ' ' + df['City'][mask]
#df['City'][mask]   = df['State'][mask]
#df['State'][mask]  = df['temp'][mask]
#df['Zip'][mask]    = df['Zip'][mask].str[-5:]

# OR

df.loc[mask, 'Street'] = df.loc[mask, 'Street'] + ' ' + df.loc[mask, 'City']
df.loc[mask, 'City']   = df.loc[mask, 'State']
df.loc[mask, 'State']  = df.loc[mask, 'temp']
df.loc[mask, 'Zip']    = df.loc[mask, 'Zip'].str[-5:]
del df['temp']

print('\n--- after ---\n')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
--- before ---

    Company                 Street          City         State       Zip
0  company1     5319 university dr      unit 143        irvine   CA92612
1  company2   55 s Lake Havasu AVE        #F-109   Lake Havasu  AZ-86403
2  company3  31752 s.coast highway     suite 300  Laguna BEACH  CA-92651
3  company4      10115 e Bell Road  Ste. 107-232    Scottsdale  AZ-85260
4  company5        686 W SUNSET DR       BURBANK            WA     99323
5  company6        08 SE 124TH AVE     VANCOUVER            WA     98684
6  company7          23077 Boyd Rd  Mount Vernom            WA     98274
7  company8       456 Bellmore Ave     Manhattan            NY     10025
8  company9     81/8 lanscaster Sq        Austin            TX     78753

--- temp ---

    Company                 Street          City         State       Zip temp
0  company1     5319 university dr      unit 143        irvine   CA92612   CA
1  company2   55 s Lake Havasu AVE        #F-109   Lake Havasu  AZ-86403   AZ
2  company3  31752 s.coast highway     suite 300  Laguna BEACH  CA-92651   CA
3  company4      10115 e Bell Road  Ste. 107-232    Scottsdale  AZ-85260   AZ
4  company5        686 W SUNSET DR       BURBANK            WA     99323  NaN
5  company6        08 SE 124TH AVE     VANCOUVER            WA     98684  NaN
6  company7          23077 Boyd Rd  Mount Vernom            WA     98274  NaN
7  company8       456 Bellmore Ave     Manhattan            NY     10025  NaN
8  company9     81/8 lanscaster Sq        Austin            TX     78753  NaN

--- mask ---

0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
Name: temp, dtype: bool

--- after ---

    Company                           Street          City State    Zip
0  company1      5319 university dr unit 143        irvine    CA  92612
1  company2      55 s Lake Havasu AVE #F-109   Lake Havasu    AZ  86403
2  company3  31752 s.coast highway suite 300  Laguna BEACH    CA  92651
3  company4   10115 e Bell Road Ste. 107-232    Scottsdale    AZ  85260
4  company5                  686 W SUNSET DR       BURBANK    WA  99323
5  company6                  08 SE 124TH AVE     VANCOUVER    WA  98684
6  company7                    23077 Boyd Rd  Mount Vernom    WA  98274
7  company8                 456 Bellmore Ave     Manhattan    NY  10025
8  company9               81/8 lanscaster Sq        Austin    TX  78753
```

Comment: hi thanks df['temp'] = df['Zip'].str.extract('([A-Z]+)') this extracts only upper case what if i want to extract both upper and lower case

Comment: regex `([A-Za-z]+)`. Or convert to upper case `.str.upper().str.extract('([A-Z]+)')`